# Custom footer html tags

Tags: wordpress, themes, footer

In my Evolve theme, there is a section to custom the footer with the following text:

```
Available HTML tags and attributes: <b> <i> <a href="" title=""> <blockquote> <del datetime=""> <ins datetime=""> <img src="" alt="" /> <ul> <ol> <li> <code> <em> <strong> <div> <span> <h1> <h2> <h3> <h4> <h5> <h6> <table> <tbody> <tr> <td> <br /> <hr />
```

When I try to use them, nothing happens, the html code is shown as simple text. 
Does anybody know this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Why not editing the footer.php?

```
<?php $footer_content = evl_get_option('evl_footer_content',''); 
 if ($footer_content === false) $footer_content = '';
 echo esc_attr($footer_content);
?>
```

Push your HTML to `$footer_content = 'insert here'`.

If we have the same version of 'Evolve' you can find it at line 88 - 91 in footer.php.